# How to read from a file into an array List of a specific object

Tags: java

I'm working on a programming project where you're suppose to write a code for an online shopping store, i have two files one with products in it and the other with accounts information and i need to read these two and store them in ArrayList and another with type accounts,, shown below in the store class, and i'm also suppose to check whether the login info is matching or not

i've tried reading both files to list1 and list2 (which are array lists of String type) and it totally worked fine but when i got to the point where i'm suppose to check if username and password are valid i tried the following:

```
    int accountIndex=-1;

    for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {

      if((list2.get(i).contains(username))&& (list2.get(i).contains(password))){
                    accountIndex=0;
                }

                }

               if(accountIndex<0) 
                   System.out.println("Login Failed! Invalid Username and/or Password.\n");
```

but it didn't work with all cases and had some bugs so my teacher told me to read files into the already existing array lists of products and accounts but i haven't found a suitable way of doing it...

this is a sample of what the account file contain:

```
0001,Salam,1234,AbdulSalam Ahmad,1223 Sultanah - Medina,05555343535,salam@hotmail.com
0002,Rawan,1111,Rawan Khaled,1223 Alaziziah - Medina,05555343435,rawan@hotmail.com
```

//main:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      int ans;
     // Craete a Store object
     Store store = new Store("Camera Online Store");
       // Read all products from the products file
     ArrayList<String>list1=new ArrayList<String>();
     File products = new File("Products.txt"); 
     try(Scanner input = new Scanner(products);) 
     {
       input.useDelimiter(",");
       while(input.hasNext()){
           list1.add(input.nextLine());

      }
      input.close();
    }

   // Read all accounts from the account file
    File customerFile = new File("Accounts.txt");
    ArrayList<String>list2=new ArrayList<String>();
    try(Scanner input = new Scanner(customerFile);) 
     {
      input.useDelimiter(",");
       while(input.hasNext()){
           list2.add(input.nextLine());

     } input.close();          
    }

    System.out.println("^^^^^^ Welcome to our "+store.getName()+" ^^^^^");
    System.out.println("*****************************************");

    while(true)
    {
    System.out.println("Are you a customer or an admin?\n  (1) for user \n  (2) for admin\n  (3) to exit");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    int choice = sc.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
            case 1: // customer mode
                System.out.println("Enter your login information.");
               System.out.print("Username:");
               String username = sc.next();
               System.out.print("Password:");
               String password = sc.next();
               int accountIndex=-1;
                for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {

                if((list2.get(i).contains(username))&& (list2.get(i).contains(password))){
                    accountIndex=0;
                }

                }

               /*
                    get the account index for this customer

               */
               if(accountIndex<0) 
                   System.out.println("Login Failed! Invalid Username and/or Password.\n");
               else{
                    do
                    {
                        System.out.println("Choose the required operations from the list below:\n  (1) Display all products \n  (2) Add a product to your shopping cart by id \n  (3) View the products in your shopping cart \n  (4) Go to checkout\n  (5) Go back to main menu");

  //Store class:

   class Store{
 private String name;
 private ArrayList<Account> arracc;
 private ArrayList<Products> arrprod;
 public Store(){

}
public void setArrAcc(Account x){
    arracc.add(x);
}
public void setArrProd(Products x){
   arrprod.add(x);
}
public Store(String name){
    this.name=name;
}
public void addProduct(Products p){
    arrprod.add(p);
}
public void deleteProduct(int id){
    arrprod.remove(id);//id is the product index

}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
```

}

```
//products class:

class Products{
 private int productID;
 private String name;
 private String supplier;
 private double price;

 public Products(){

 }
public Products(int productID,String name,String supplier, double price){
    this.productID=productID;
    this.name=name;
    this.supplier=supplier;
    this.price=price;
}
public void setProductID(int ID){
    productID=ID;
}
public void setName(String newName){
    name=newName;
}
public void setSupplier(String newSupplier){
    supplier=newSupplier;
}
public void setPrice(double newPrice){
    price=newPrice;
}
public int getID(){
    return productID;
}
public String getSupplier(){
    return supplier;
}
public String getNAme(){
    return name;
}
public double getPrice(){
    return price;
}
public String toString(){
    return" Product ID: "+productID+"\n -Product Name: "+name+"\n -Product Supplier: "+supplier+
            "\n -Product Price: "+price+"\n ******************************************";
}
```

}

any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading contents of a file into class objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32265533/reading-contents-of-a-file-into-class-objects)

Comment: In your post, you show the contents of the Accounts file as a long single comma delimited string. Is this truly the way the data is formatted within the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading in lines of text from a data file using Scanner, don't use the [Scanner#next()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm) method unless you specifically want each token (word) from the file. It's specifically designed for retrieving tokens (words) from a file when used with the [Scanner#hasNext()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnext.htm) method. Use [**Scanner#hasNextLine()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnextline.htm) in conjunction with the [**Scanner#nextLine()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) method instead. Here is an example:

```
File customerFile = new File("Accounts.txt");
ArrayList<String> accountsList = new ArrayList<>();
// Try With Resources...
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(customerFile)) {
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine().trim(); // Trim each line as they are read.
        if (line.equals("")) { continue; }     // Make sure a data line is not blank.
        accountsList.add(line);                // Add the data line to Account List
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

You will notice that I don't name the Account List as **list2**. Although it's a matter of preference it's simply not descriptive enough. I conveniently named it **accountsList** which makes it much easier to see what the variable is for.

Although you can get away with it, I wouldn't use the **contains()** method for checking **User Name** and **Password**. It's not accurate enough as you will find when the Account List would get larger. Instead, split each account line into a String Array and access the specific indexes where the **User Names** and **Passwords** would reside, for example:

```
int accountIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < accountsList.size(); i++) {
    // Split the current accounts data line into a String Array
    String[] userData = accountsList.get(i).split(",");
    // Check User Name/Password valitity.
    if (userData[1].equals(username) && userData[2].equals(password)) {
        accountIndex = i;
        break;    // Success - We found it. Stop Looking.
    }
}
```

Now, this of course is under the assumption that in each Account data line the first item is a ID Number, the second item is the User Name and the thirst item is the Password. If this line was split into a String array that would then make the first item (ID) reside at Array Index 0, the second item (User Name) reside at Array Index 1, and the third item (Password) reside at Array Index 2, and so on.

You also have a variable named **accountIndex** (good name) but upon a successful find of the User Name and Password you supply **0** to this variable. By doing this you are effectively telling your code that the successful account is actually the very first account contained within the Accounts List regardless of what User Name and Password has passed validity. What you should be passing to this variable is the value contained in **i** as demonstrated in the example above since this is the true index value of the Accounts List element which passed User Name/Password validity.

The rest of your code has not been supplied therefore you are on your own from here.

Comment: Thank you very much!! and sorry i'm still a bigenner and i know i should pay more attention at naming my variables! Thank you again!